# Prevent unwanted Toggling in a Timer

Tags: arduino

I have a problem with arduino due timers. First let me explain what i know of them.I don't know if there is a way to solve this issue for general timers. Due timers features:

1) They always start from zero,

2) They work as UP-COUNTING or UP-DOWN counting timers,

3) Each timer has two compare registers.

My project involves cases to work in sampled times(period), i.e. timer runs for a sampled time and based on values in compare registers the outputs TIOA and TIOB toggles.I am working in up-down mode.  Now the problem is when I have zero in a compare register I expect a zero output (on TIOA and TIOB) for whole period. But the timer is toggling output for zero comparison also. i.e. instead of getting a zero always i am getting a square wave with (2*period) as its time period. Is this common problem for other timers also?

Can you guys suggest me a workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <AdvaDueTC.h>

int default_clock  = 1;
int RCcntS = 2187*2;
int period0 = 65536;
int a  = 2180;
int b  = 0;

void subrtn()
{
changeTC_TC3_Period(RCcntS);    // loading sampler TC3 with RCcntS

changeTC_TC0_Period(RCcntS/2,a,b);  // loading timer TC0 with RCcntT  

}
void setup() {

 setupTC3_Interrupt(period0,default_clock ,subrtn);//setup sampler interrupt 

 setupTC_TC0_Timing(period0, default_clock); 

}

void loop() {
 // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

functions used are :

Here TC3 is in UP mode and TC0 is in UPDOWN mode of operation. TIOA0 and TIOB0 are used for obtaining toggling output.(i.e. in REG_TC0_CMR0, ACPA,BCPB are set to 3). Here TIOB0 is toggling and I want to stay at one valve (0 or 3.3v) for whole period.

Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: as usual for any question on SO, you should give an example of the code you've tried so far. One code is worth a million explanations!

Answer (score 0):

> when I have zero in a compare register I expect a zero output

i expect the output to be triggered two times (UP and DOWN) every tick (i think you call it period), because the timer is overflowing EVERY tick.

Solution is turn off the timer comparison.

this seems to me a PWM, maybe you'll get better result using the dedicated HW

Answer (score 0):

Yes what you said is correct. At first I couldn't get it but this MCU timer has option to set or clear the timer output value for whole period. so without going for TOGGLE always, I used these options to get desired operation.